# How can I zip an object in S3 Bucket using Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I am pretty new to Amazon S3 and working on something with S3. I have uploaded many files to S3 bucket using Java. I have objects in S3 with a name like Demo/demo1.txt, Demo/demo2.txt, Demo/demo3.txt. I have almost 1000 individual files till demo1000.txt under Demo/. I have uploaded them from Java using below code

```
s3Client.upload(bucketName, inputStream, objectKey, ObjectMetaData);
```

How can I zip that entire demo/ object containing those 1000 files in S3 itself using AWS API for Java?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if, instead, you uploaded a zip file in the first place?

Comment: Download the objects, zip them up locally using your preferred Java zip library or some other way (e.g. zip tool), upload the ZIP file to S3, delete the old objects as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Java does not offer operations to ZIP up files. However, you can write custom Java logic to perform this use case. Creating backend logic to dynamically zip certian files (ie - images) is a valid use case.

For example, in the below photo asset management app, JPG files are retrieved based on a user selecting tags. Then the corresponding files are retrieved from an S3 bucket, placed into a ZIP file, stored in a separate bucket and the ZIP file is presigned to the user can retrieve the JPG files that match the tags.

Refer to the below document that includes dynamically zipping image files. The Java logic you are looking for is in the ***Photo Asset Management*** example that you can find here in the AWS Code Library.

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html)

See the  `public byte[] listBytesToZip()` method in the `S3Service` class.